# Can't get rid of webpack-dev-server status bar

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am not able to remove the 'App ready' status bar at the top of my page when building and using the localhost URL provided by webpack-dev-server. Here are the following things I've found and the steps I've taken:

- Noticed the webpack-dev-server GitHub page states there are some issues with Webpack and NodeJS version 7.

  - Uninstalled version 7.2.0 from my machine and installed 6.9.1
- Uninstalled and reinstalled both Webpack and Webpack-dev-server globally using npm.
- Removed and recreated the bundle.js file from my Webpack project.
- Performed a hard refresh, and then cleared all cookies.
- First used Edge, and then tried Chrome.

In all of these tests and reconfigurations, I am using the --inline parameter to run the server. What am I missing?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/13

Comment: I've just tried the suggested configuration, and it did not work. When trying to add the URL to the entry, I receive an error when building. It seems I am unfamiliar enough with Webpack that I don't know where to point the entry to in order to set this up properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check you `webpack.config.js` for `devServer` section. They can override you passing options to `webpack-dev-server`. For example, there could be `inline: false` that will prevent passing `--inline` options to `webpack-dev-server` from CLI.